# 2.5 HDD making weird noise after the power got shut down

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my hard drive making weird noises after the power got shut down?](https://superuser.com/questions/222097/why-is-my-hard-drive-making-weird-noises-after-the-power-got-shut-down)

The HDD used in my work place is making a weird sound after the power was shut down. Is it safe to open the 2.5 HDD? What else can I do?

Comment: It is hard to say ... Could you post record of that sound? Just kidding. It could be broken head, engine, whatever. It can be end of its life as well. In my opinion it is little risky..

Comment: belongs to hddfault.com :-)... I think superuser is your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do don't touch any of  the metal components within the drive if there is any power running to it.

Does it sounds like the inner disc may be in contact with the housing during rotation or does it sound more like an electric motor dying?

Comment: it sound like clicking on the keybord

Comment: check this out:
http://www.duxcw.com/yabbse/index.php?board=5;action=display;threadid=7102